@font-face not working with child theme in Wordpress
I have looked through a lot of the past forum Q&A about @font-face and have tried everything I can see to rectify the issue.
Converted the fonts into woff and woff2 using fontsquirrel.
Simply the font is not appearing on the site. Im not sure if it is a code issue with my CSS or if I am missing a piece of PHP code that needs to be added, or if the theme (Manon) is causing some kind of overriding.
style.css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'pp_gosha_sansbold';
    src: url('../fonts/ppgoshasans-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/ppgoshasans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'pp_gosha_sansregular';
    src: url('../fonts/ppgoshasans-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/ppgoshasans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

Additional CSS in customisation section on wordpress
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, ul, li, a {
    font-family: 'pp_gosha_sansbold', sans-serif;
}

p {
    font-family: 'pp_gosha_sansregular', sans-serif;
}

Fonts are in the following folder on server:
public_html/wp-content/themes/manon-child/fonts
CSS for child theme in:
public_html/wp-content/themes/manon-child
Any help would be really appreciated
I have tried to check the URL, changing it to most alternatives:
../fonts/ppgoshasans-bold-webfont.woff2
public_html/
Also the full URL which I checked through the browser and allowed me download the font so I guess it was right.

Since we're talking about wordpress: your parent theme or a pagebuilder plugin (e.g. elementor) may introduce quite specific CSS rules so element based rules like p or h1 will be overridden. Try a font path like fonts/ppgoshasans-regular-webfont.woff2 (no leading slashes, if the fonts are really in your child theme directory it should work) and a more specific rule like body p{font-family:pp_gosha_sansregular!important;} - just for testing. Also inspect your elements via dev tools: you should at least get some info whether the font-family is at some point applied and maybe overriden.

If not the problem may actually be that your child theme CSS is not correctly enqueued. To exclude this bug you may test something stupid like body{background-color:red;}. Besides, you should definitely fix the aforementioned jquery error. Your display may heavily rely on it - you should also try to disable any caching/optimization plugins which may prevent the current CSS to be rendered due to caching/inlining. (E.g autoptimize, cache enabler etc.)

Your fonts are kept in the directory public_html/wp-content/themes/manon-child/fonts, and the CSS file is in public_html/wp-content/themes/manon-child. However the @font-face in your CSS file is not pointing to the fonts directory; it is a relative path that points to public_html/wp-content/themes/fonts.
In relative paths, ../ means 'the parent directory'. For a CSS file in the directory public_html/wp-content/themes/manon-child, a path of ../ points to public_html/wp-content/themes. So when your CSS file as a font-face src of ../fonts/ppgoshasans-bold-webfont.woff2, it is pointing to a location that doesn't exist.
You can check this by opening your browser's developer tools (press F12 in most browsers) and going to the Network tab. You'll likely see a 404 error for the font files that you're trying to load, and if you inspect the URL, you'll be able to see and debug the actual incorrect URL it's trying to load.
To fix your CSS, change the path segment from ../ to ./.
./ means 'the current directory.
@font-face {
    font-family: 'pp_gosha_sansbold';
    src: url('./fonts/ppgoshasans-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('./fonts/ppgoshasans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}


Thanks for the reply, i've replaced the css with the one you sent, unfortunately it is still not working. There is only one error in the network tab which is to do with a jquery.
